# Bigquery - How to filter records with certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write SQL (in BigQuery) the following in order to get a result that satisfies the following conditions.
for ex: my table contains the following data

```
id         | value
___________|_____________
1          | p
1          | oo
2          | p
4          | p
4          | lop
5          | AA
5          | p
6          | p
6          | p
```

I want to filter out records where it contains only value as "p" from the table.
The expected result would be

```
2          | p
6          | p
```

I have tried with the following query but it returns other rows as well (1,p  and 1,oo)

```
SELECT id,value
FROM `ggg.tt.table` where userid in 
(
   select id from (SELECT id,COUNT(distinct value )as cnt
   from (select * FROM `ggg.tt.table` where trim(value) = 'p' 
     )group by 1 having cnt = 1))
```

can someone help how to achieve this using bigquery ?

Comment: If this is for bigquery, why tag it as mysql? Please only tag the DBMS you are Actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the distinct values for every id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`id` int, `value` varchar(3))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`id`, `value`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'p'),
>     (1, 'oo'),
>     (2, 'p'),
>     (4, 'p'),
>     (4, 'lop'),
>     (5, 'AA'),
>     (5, 'p'),
>     (6, 'p'),
>     (6, 'p')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT id 
> FROm  tab1 t1 
> WHERE `value` = 'p' AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `value`) FROM tab1 WHERE id = t1.id)  = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  6 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c90750627c157ef4980efaf498351bd)*

Answer (score 4):

Use below approach

```
select id
from `ggg.tt.table`
group by id
having countif(value != 'p') = 0
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> what if i want column "value" as well in result

In case if for some reason you need `value` in the output - even though it is always `p` as per definition of you case - consider below

```
select id, any_value(value) value
from `ggg.tt.table` t
group by id
having countif(t.value != 'p') = 0
```

with output

[image]

Comment: what if i want column "value" as well in result

Comment: in your case the value is known, so you can just add ` 'p' as value` - right?

Comment: @bigd - by definition the value is always `'p'`, so why would you need to include the value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,value
FROM `ggg.tt.table` 
WHERE TRIM(value) = 'p' AND 
      id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `ggg.tt.table` WHERE TRIM(value) != 'p')
```

Comment: this will result other unwanted value as well                                                                             id         | value
________|_____________
1          | p
1          | oo

Comment: Have you tested it?
I ran it on the same values as you provided and got the desired result of:
2, p
6, p

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  cte AS (
select 1 as Id ,'p'   as value  union all
select 1 as Id ,'p'   as value union all
select 1 as Id ,'oo'  as value union all
select 2 as Id ,'p'   as value union all
select 4 as Id ,'p'   as value union all
select 4 as Id ,'lop' as value union all
select 5 as Id ,'AA'  as value union all
select 5 as Id ,'p'   as value union all
select 6 as Id ,'p'   as value union all
select 6 as Id ,'p'   
  ),
  cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    value
  FROM
    cte
  WHERE
    value != 'p' )
SELECT
  id,
  count(distinct value)
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    cte2)
group by id
```